# jQuery Dialog bug when opening it for the first time

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have jQuery dialog popup that will show notices by clicking the link for the chosen notice. Data is loaded to the popup from database. All this works, but I have this strange bug when I open the popup after refreshing the notice page. The bug happens when the popup opens for the first time, position is all wrong and the "close" -button is still using the dialog UI css that should be removed. All works fine after the first time and second time I open popup it works fine without any problems and button colour and position are correct.

Here is the jQuery script I use:

```
$(function() {
  $( ".dialog" ).dialog({autoOpen: false}); 
  $(".load_data").on("click", function() {
    var url = this.href;  // get the url from the anchor
    var dialog = $(".dialog2").dialog({
      show: "fade",
      hide: "fade",
      width: "auto",
      height: "auto",
      title: "Notice",
      closeOnEscape: true,
      modal: true,
      position: "center",
      open: function() {
        $('button').removeClass('ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only ui-state-hover');
        //removes jquery css from button
        $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find('button:contains("Close")').addClass('button_cancel');
        //add css to close button
      },    
      buttons: {
        "Close": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
    }); // get DOM element
    // load remote content
    dialog.load(
      url, // to the url from the anchor href attribute
      {},
      function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        // success callback
        dialog.dialog();  // show the dialog                        
      }                         
    );                  

    return false; // prevent the default action on the anchor
  });
  $(".open_notice" ).click(function() {
    $( ".dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    return false;       
  });
});
```

Comment: Toggle the classes instead of removing them, and toggle them back on when you close the dialog. The dialog itself is only created once, so it is not rebuilt to the original form after the first close as your expecting it too. Also - recreating each click will leak memory in IE very badly.

Comment: Instantiate the dialog directly on the element first with autoOpen set to false, THEN use `dialog("open"/"close")` to toggle the dialog in the click function.